# Add a quick link to Stack Exchange filters to every page on the network

Tags: feature-request, stackexchange.com, tag-filters

The Stack Exchange site includes the nice "filter" feature, allowing users to create custom question streams by specifying which tags on which sites should show up in the filter.

These streams, however, are not easily reachable from most pages. When you are not on Stack Exchange itself, there are two possible ways of reaching them:

- If you are viewing any question listing that shows your tags on the right sidebar, there's a link titled "tag subscriptions" beneath the tags. You have to follow it and then select the filter you want to view.
- From any other page, you can go to the Stack Exchange main site (e.g. by the link inside the Stack Exchange menu) and navigate there to "tagged questions", then to the desired filter.

This seems unnecessarily complicated, especially when one has several filters defined.

I therefore suggest to add a "my filters" menu item into the Stack Exchange menu, to the left of "inbox", that opens a list showing all filters a user has defined.

Rationale: Filters are just another stream of questions, much like the 'hot questions' that are already there. Compared to those, filters may even deliver more relevant questions to the user, because 'hot questions' include lots of questions from sites where the user may not have an account (and may not be knowledgeable).

Comment: There's another argument I forgot to include: I generally look for those lists when I start using Stack Exchange on a given day, and *when I just answered a question*. In this "one question down, let's see if there are others I can answer" situation, an easily reachable, direct link to the filters would be very helpful.